# Use the binomial theorem to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(3-4x)(2x+3)^7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a basic-to-ok understanding of using the binomial theorem but the formula I follow starts with the form of $(a+b)^n$ and so I am not clear how to convert $(3-4x)(2x+3)^7$ to $(a+b)^n$ so I can follow through to find the coefficient.

Comment: what has been tried this looks similar to your last question.

Comment: yeah, it is the same process but starting with a different expansion. I am not sure how to expand it when there are two bracket groups

Comment: you could expand them separately and FOIL or convert the first into near multiple of the base of the second etc. , try not to delete this one when you figure it out. we are not a homework question and answer site.

Comment: I only deleted the last one because I realised I made a small mistake that threw off my whole question. With no answers I deleted it to make sure I didn't waste someone else's time answering the question that I no longer needed.

Comment: you could have self answered the question and got it off the unanswered question list.

Comment: Sorry, did not realise you could self answer. Still learning this site. I will try separate expansion and FOIL, and self answer if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no direct method to convert it into the form $(a+b)^n$

you can apply binomial theorem to $(2x+3)^7$ and find the coefficient of $x^4\ (let \ it\ be\ a)$ and $x^5\ (let\ it\ be\ b)$ then coeffient of $x^5$ can be found by simply multiplying $(3-4x)$ to the expansion and only using the coefficients $a$ and $b$

Comment: 3-4x= -4x+3 = -2(2x+3) +9 so you can make this mostly a sum of powers of the second base.

Comment: great! didn't notice that :P

Comment: which means it's expressible as $-2(2x+3)^8+9(2x+3)^7$